# acro 3.3 format listing

Tags: multicol, acro

This is my first entry, please excuse if I can not explain my problem perfectly in the first go, but here is my issue:

I use the `acro` package in version 3.3, which is important to mention, as I can find many solutions for earlier versions but not for this one.
I have something like 30 acronyms like

```
\DeclareAcronym{CMOS}{
    short = CMOS,
    long  = complementary metal oxide semiconductor,
    tag = abbrev
}
```

and the implementation in the text works well, but the listing doesn't look as I would like it.

I want a 2 column design, which goes over more than one page.
This can be solved by using the standard template

```
list/template  = description,
```

and using the package `multicol`.
However in that case I miss the tab between the "short" and the "long" part.

This would be solved by using the `longtable` template, but `longtable` doesn't support `multicol`. So I actually lost so much time on trying to solve this that I just would like to ask you guys for a solution.
I believe there is a simple format definition, that should solve it, but I can not find it in the documentation.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list to achieve a layout like that. Maybe the `labeling` list from KOMA-Script (already available if you are using a class like `scrartcl` or `scrbook` and available in other classes through the `scrextend` package) is an easy solution:

```
\begin{labeling}{widest label}
  \item[foo] lorem ipsum
  \item[bar] ...
\end{labeling}
```

This list can be combined with the `multicols` environment. You can define your own list template for `acro` using both. The example below asumes that you do neither use the `alt`, `extra` or `foreign` properties of `acro` nor the page numbers. (All of them could be added to the template, though):

```
\NewAcroTemplate[list]{twocolumn}{%
  \begin{multicols}{2}[\acroheading]
    \acropreamble
    \begin{labeling}{XXXXX}
      \acronymsmapF
        {\item[\bfseries\acrowrite{short}] \acrowrite{list}}
        {\item\AcroRerun}
    \end{labeling}
  \end{multicols}
}
```

A complete example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{scrextend}

\NewAcroTemplate[list]{twocolumn}{%
  \begin{multicols}{2}[\acroheading]
    \acropreamble
    \begin{labeling}{XXXXX}
      \acronymsmapF
        {\item[\bfseries\acrowrite{short}] \acrowrite{list}}
        {\item\AcroRerun}
    \end{labeling}
  \end{multicols}
}

\acsetup{
  list/template = twocolumn
}

\DeclareAcronym{CMOS}{
  short = CMOS,
  long  = complementary metal oxide semiconductor
}

\DeclareAcronym{DMSO}{
  short = DMSO,
  long  = Dimethyl sulfoxide
}

\DeclareAcronym{a}{
  short = A,
  long  = the letter A
}

\DeclareAcronym{xx}{
  short = foo,
  long  = an example
}

\DeclareAcronym{blub}{
  short = xx,
  long  = nonsense
}

\begin{document}

\acuseall
\printacronyms

\end{document}
```

Comment: Amazing you saved my day - really, thank you so much I'm so grateful you can not imagine how many days I already spend on that ! Just on small addition, is there a way to set the length of the tab (or first item) to a larger (longer) value ?

Comment: @Mkubik yes, there is. The argument of the `labeling` determines which width it should use. I went for `{XXXXX}` in the example but you can use `{\hspace{2cm}}` or more Xs `{XXXXXX}` or what ever suits your needs. (This obviously is not as comfortable as a table which determines the width automatically, but…)

Comment: Thanks a lot, seriously amazing you made one guy real happy today

Comment: @ cgnieder, sorry I deleted my added question as i found the issue, I was trying to make a minimalist example and thereby I noticed that the issue is related with the fact that I forced the hyphenation to stop with: 
\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000 
by using a too long word in the description it extended over the boarder and I thought that this is a result of a bad width definition, but it isn't. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thank you so much also from me. The manual needs work in my opinion, it is really hard to follow in some cases.